# get variables from Google Maps with JSON

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

What am I doing wrong here? I want to get the latitude and longitude from a postcode with Google Maps, this is easy enough and I am getting the results but I cannot seem to save them. Here is what I am using. I just need to get and save the `lng` and `lat`, but there seems to be more than 1; I want the one in 'location'.

```
$get_pickup_coords = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?&address=cv57bt&sensor=false";
$pickup_data = @file_get_contents($get_pick_coords);
$pickup_result = json_decode($pickup_data, true);   

$latitude = $pickup_result[3];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of errors in your script. For starters, you're using an xml output and trying to `json_decode` it. Corrected this by passing the `json` parameter in the google api instead of `xml`.

Secondly, `$pickup_result[3]` won't give you the lat longs, get it as shown below:

```
$get_pickup_coords = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=cv57bt&sensor=false";
$pickup_data = file_get_contents($get_pickup_coords);
$pickup_result = json_decode($pickup_data, true);   
$lat = $pickup_result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$long = $pickup_result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```

`$lat` and `$long` variables contain the latitude and longitude respectively.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you upvote the answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=cv57bt";
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );
$location=$data->results[0]->geometry->location;

echo 'Latitude:',$location->lat,' Longitude:',$location->lng;
```